# "CASE" in SQL Query not work with string values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have Simple “Case” query that work with number but not work with string?

It Work Correctly:

```
SELECT
OrderItem_ID,Cost,
Case
    When Cost = 0 then 555
    Else Cost
End As CostStatus
FROM
    OrderItem
```

It Doesn’t work:

```
    SELECT
    OrderItem_ID,Cost,
    Case
        When Cost = 0 then "Free"
        Else Cost
    End As CostStatus
    FROM
        OrderItem
```

Error is:
Invalid column name 'Free'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the results from a CASE expression should return the same data type or need to be implicitly converted following data precedence. In this case, numeric types have a higher precedence than string data types. Therefore, you need to use an explicit conversion.

```
SELECT
OrderItem_ID,Cost,
Case
    When Cost = 0 then 'Free'
    Else CAST( Cost AS varchar(13))
End As CostStatus
FROM
    OrderItem
```

EDIT: I changed the double quotes to single quotes which are the standard in T-SQL. Double quotes will only work if QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS is OFF. Both problems were present in the query presented.

Comment: I suspect the OP wants the literal string `'Free'`. `"Free"` would be interpreted as a column name.

Comment: The invalid column name error suggests QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is on. If so string literals must be single quoted.

Comment: It depends on the setting for quoted_identifier. But to be safe, I'll just edit the answer to use single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

SQL strings are normally enclosed by `'` rather than `"`.  *(MS Access is an example where `"` is used, but SQL Standard is `'`, including for SQL Server)*

That gives you this...

```
SELECT
OrderItem_ID,Cost,
Case
    When Cost = 0 then 'Free'
    Else Cost
End As CostStatus
FROM
    OrderItem
```

But then you're trying to put a string *(`'free'`)* in the same column as a bunch of numbers: `costStatus`.

Do you want that column to be a string column or a numeric column?  It ***can't*** be both...

Maybe you should have two columns?  You already have the `cost` column on its own, so maybe just have `'free'` and `'not free'` as two possible status values?

```
SELECT
OrderItem_ID,
Cost,
Case
    When Cost = 0 then 'Free'
    Else 'Not Free'
End As CostStatus
FROM
    OrderItem
```

If it's just so you can replace the `0.00` in a report with the word `free`, you shouldn't do that in SQL.  You should do it in the report *(or whatever presentation layer you have)*.